# Get attribute values from html elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a bit stuck. I'd like to get the attribute value `"for"` using a jquery selector. Though I am able to successfully log to the console, how can I get/log just the value for the attribute `"for"` on the labels? I've tried `console.log(labels['for'])` but that isn't the way to go. Below is the related code.

***HTML:***

```
<div class="inline-group" id="album_set-group">
  <h2>Albums</h2> 
  <div class="inline-related"> 
    <h3><b>Album:</b>&nbsp;<span class="inline_label">#1</span></h3>
    <fieldset class="module aligned ">
      <div class="form-row field-name">
        <div>
          <label for="id_album_set-0-name">Name:</label> <input id="id_album_set-0-name" maxlength="100" name="album_set-0-name" type="text"> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row field-release_date">
        <div class="date-field">
          <label for="id_album_set-0-release_date">Release date:</label> <input id="id_album_set-0-release_date" name="album_set-0-release_date" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var labels = $( "#album_set-group" ).find( "label" );
   console.log(labels);
});
```

Comment: To get attribute of all labels, you will have to use `loop/.each`.. Use `.attr(ATTR_NAME)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read http://api.jquery.com/attr/ for get attr

try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var labels = $("#album_set-group").find("label");
   labels.each(function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('for'));
   });
});
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/xo67uqc7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use just the method .attr(). In your case you can do something like

```
$("#album_set-group").find("label").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('for'));
});
```

Comment: CMedina gave me a more complete answer with reference and a jsfiddle, so I accepted his answer. I gave yours an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Plain JavaScript:

- Collect the `<label>`s into a NodeList with `querySelectorAll()`
- Convert NodeList into an array with `Array.prototype.slice.call()`
- Iterate through the array and on each iteration, use `getAttribute()` to get the `for` attribute.
- `push` each `for` into a new array.
- `console.log(newArray)`

**Snippet**

```js
var labelList = document.querySelectorAll('label');
var labelArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(labelList);
var total = labelList.length;
var forArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  var forAttr = labelArray[i].getAttribute('for');
  forArray.push(forAttr);
}

console.log('for: ' + forArray);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-group" id="album_set-group">
  <h2>Albums</h2> 
  <div class="inline-related">
    <h3><b>Album:</b>&nbsp;<span class="inline_label">#1</span></h3>
    <fieldset class="module aligned ">
      <div class="form-row field-name">
        <div>
          <label for="id_album_set-0-name">Name:</label>
          <input id="id_album_set-0-name" maxlength="100" name="album_set-0-name" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row field-release_date">
        <div class="date-field">
          <label for="id_album_set-0-release_date">Release date:</label>
          <input id="id_album_set-0-release_date" name="album_set-0-release_date" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```